# Need some information regarding data warehousing field

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I am a web developer and i would like to shift my field to data warehousing.
Can anyone please give me some idea , which langauges or stuff i need to learn like cogonos , datastage, etl

or IF anyone  currently working can guide me how can i start , i will thankful to you.
DO i nned to do oracle because i know mysql , sql. My basic understanding with databse is good.
Any books

Comment: Just an opinion but if your a developer then dont just learn one aspect of software development. Learn as much as you can about all aspects of software delelopment. Switching from one technology to another is what a developer should be able to do.  Dont just do it for change, but to learn.

Comment: I'll say it in a comment for damage control: Learn Postgres. Other than technical superiority, it now has a perceived edge politically, and it has more synergy.

Comment: @EvanCarroll in data warehousing PostgreSQL is still limited -- manual partitioning, materialised views are well behind the leaders ... I wouldn't rule it out for a small data warehouse, but in the corporate world of Informatica, Cognos, Business Objects etc, Oracle would be closer to what companies are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some books to start with.  Toolkits you choose can be based upon whichever toolkit is in use where you are working.  Most Data Warehousing professionals adhere to either Kimball's methods or Inmon's, so having knowledge about both should help you in the future.  I included the other, because I respect the work of Imhoff and Geiger.  I was lucky when I started, I was asked to take over maintenance of an existing Proof of Concept Data Warehouse.  Good luck, and if you need any help, let us know on StackOverflow! The books I provided so far are general design and methodology books which are technology neutral.  With good knowledge of these methodologies, and some specific training on tools, you should be able to work with any BI stack.  You might want to try several toolkits to find one that fits your style.  I have worked with the Microsoft toolkit almost exclusively, but I have touched on Cognos and Hyperion at various times in the past, and the place I am on contract to right now is switching to Informatica for ETL.  They all have good and bad points, so it comes down to being adaptable and a quick learner, just like any other IT job.  As a web developer, you probably used many tools depending upon what you did, i.e. you learned HTML first and then did some CSS and maybe some javascript, you may have also used tools like coldfusion.  But the point is once you knew the basics, like what I presented below, the tools were secondary.
[Kimball's Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247)
[Mastering Data Warehouse Design (Imhoff, Galemmo, Geiger)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471324213)
[Inmon's Building the Data Warehouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764599445)

Comment: If i have to go for database course , which one should i prefer with respect to data warehousing from oracle , MSSQL , Postgresql , mysql.
I mean which is more widely used in datawarehousing from ur experience.
I need to do the course.

Comment: If you have a place in mind for your first opportunity, then by all means get familiar with the database technology that they use. Most BI toolkits are associated with one database, so that may drive what you learn first from a tools perspective, but most places I have worked including all of the large (Fortune 1000 sized) companies that I have worked for (about 3 to 5) have had more than one database technology in place. Most of the toolkits will also retrieve data from multiple databases as well. So, pick one and be prepared to learn at least a little about them all.

Comment: What size company are you targeting for employment.  Most large companies will use DataStage, Cognos, Teradata, AbInitio, Informatica, etc. Middle sized companies and companies just starting into BI will likely use Microsoft tools (SSIS, SSAS, SSRS) since the cost is lower, although some very large companies also use these.  Smaller companies either have not started into BI or may be using the open source toolkits (Pentaho, mySql, Kettle, etc). Of course, if a person used a toolkit in one place then is picked to start BI at another company, they will most likely use the tools they already know

Comment: I am looking to go into IBM. I am also thinking of doing COGNOS certification because my friend is working at IBM and he told me that once idonr cognos certification i can enter in company. I am confused between MIcrosoft SQL or oracle. What is ur recommendation if i had to choose one database